# .Mov file corrupted after QuickTime Exporting for web

Tags: video, video-quality, quicktime

I recently attempted to export a large video file to the web through QuickTime Pro in hopes of uploading it to my web storage account and put on my website. However, when I encoded this .mov file, somewhere in the process it became corrupted and it appears as a much smaller file. I can play the file on my computer locally, but when I upload it to my web storage account I can no longer access/play it. It also appears as a much smaller file. This is the only file of the movie I have on my computer so I find it curious that it plays locally but cannot be accessed online. Please let me know if you have any suggestions as to how to fix this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you've uploaded a reference movie file, because this kind of movie is much smaller, and can not play without it's master. What you need is a self-contained movie.

My suggestion: To avoid this, try to export your movie via the "***Export…***"-Item, but **not with "*Export for Web…*"**. So you'll get a self-contained movie.